# Is it possible to use filecheck to match values from another file inside a CMAKE project?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, tdd, llvm

I am working on a LLVM pass that dumps a json file as one of its output when run over a test.ll file (represented by %s in filecheck)

Here is the commands inside my test.ll file

```
; RUN: opt-load %bindir/MY-PASS.so -json-filename output.json -run-my-pass %s -S -disable-output
; RUN: cat output.json | FileCheck %testdir/output-target.json
```

My `${PROJ_DIR}/Tests` folder has:

- `${PROJ_DIR}/Tests/test.ll` file
- `${PROJ_DIR}/Tests/output-target.json` file

After configuring my project with CMAKE on ${BUILD_DIR} folder and running `make check` I face the issue where make check cannot find output-target.json

`make check` is able to generate `output.json` in  `${BUILD_DIR}/Tests/` folder but it is not able to find the target file `%testdir/output-target.json` which expands to `${BUILD_DIR}/Tests/Output/test.ll.tmpestdir/output-target.json`

Should I be using something different than `%testdir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the predefined [substitutions](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/lit.html#pre-defined-substitutions) in `lit`, more specifically the `%p` along with the `test_source_root` (see the same URL provided) configuration variable for test discovery.

So, what I usually end up doing is to provide a `lit.cfg.in` template for `cmake`'s `configure_file` command, in order to get a `lit.cfg` in the build directory, something along the lines of:

```
# aggregate unit test targets under a pseudo-target
add_custom_target(check)

configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lit.cfg.in" "lit.cfg")

add_custom_target(lit_tests
COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -m lit.main "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" -v)

add_dependencies(lit_tests ${TESTEE_LIB})
add_dependencies(check lit_tests)
```

This also allows me to run `lit` tests by typing `make check` in the build directory.

Then in my `lit.cfg.in` I add this:

```
config.test_source_root = '@CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@'
config.substitutions.append(('%outputdatadir', "%p/data/output"))
```

So in my case, `%p` ends up being `[absolute-path-to-project-test-root-dir]/data/output`, where I keep expected text outputs from test cases.

Finally in a specific test case `.ll` file I can use:

```
; RUN: diff -w %t %outputdatadir/output-target.json
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `%p` and the substitution link. Really helpful.